# The code works but it lags when it works. It works with foreach and loop it

Tags: c#, arraylist, foreach

When the code is working so laggy it would be very good so that it is not laggy when it works.

How the code works:

It searches the computer for a file is then when it find it to change the file but if the file is running line will loop until it manages to do its job.

Main class

```
public Form1(string[] Args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }    

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // One second.Thread.Sleep(1000); // One second.
        MessageBox.Show("Testing");
        Fille mc = new Fille();
        mc.Search();
    }
```

Fille clss

```
private static ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
private static ArrayList listRemove = new ArrayList();


public void Search()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\MCFILE\trrtrt\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                // Display file path.
                if (SHA1Hash.GetSHA1Hash(file) == "1233456") // fake SHA1Hash
                {
                    try
                    {
                        COPYWithReplace(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\MCFILE\Fake2\Test.exe", file);
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        // log errors
                        if (list2.Count == 0)
                        {
                            list2.Add(file);
                            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test2));
                            thread.Start();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test2));
                            thread.Abort();
                            list2.Add(file);
                            thread.Join();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log errors
        }
    }

private void Test2()
    {
        if (list2.Count == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (string _item in list2)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Run
                    COPYWithReplace(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\MCFILE\Fake2\Test.exe", _item);
                    listRemove.Add(_item);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    //error
                }
            }
            foreach (var Remove in listRemove)
            {
                list2.Remove(Remove);
            }
            listRemove.Clear();
            if (list2.Count == 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test2));
                thread.Start();
            }

        }
    }
```

I made a new thread because I found the problem. But now it's just that it lags.

Comment: What do you mean by *it lags*? Have you tried anything to find out where, specifically, the problem is?

Comment: It is loop as lags. foreach

Comment: When the loop this code again and then lags it. Test2() ---> foreach

Comment: I thought maybe I could get an idea of what you're trying to do from reading the code, since your question is unintelligible. But in this case your code is even more convoluted than your text description. Can you tell us in words what you're trying to accomplish, and explain what you mean by "it lags?"

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HRgO0Kp.png The picture explains more how it works.
It will change the files if it does not succeed in this so try it if it succeed.

Comment: OK, so you're looping though all ".exe" files in or under some directory, and for each one that matches a hash code, you're overwriting it with some other file.  If that fails, then you launch a background thread to try again.  1. How many ".exe" files found?  2. How many IOExceptions?  3. What are the messages in the IOExceptions?  4. ArrayList is not thread safe, you must use a [thread safe collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason it's "lagging" is because you have the system in a very convoluted but rather processor intensive and I/O intensive loop. If a file fails the first test, your code starts a thread that tries it again. And if that fails then you start another thread to try it again, lather, rinse, repeat.

That's going to absolutely *kill* performance. You're basically doing this:

```
while (forever)
{
    if I can overwrite the file
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Except if you have multiple files that you're trying to write, then you're doing that loop for every file. Concurrently. And you're not just using a loop. Instead, you're starting and stopping threads like nobody's business.

Yeah, that's going to slow down your computer.

A more reasonable way to do this would be with a thread to do the first check, and a timer that will limit how often you do the other checks. Communication is with a simple queue, because only one thread will be accessing it at a time.

Here's what I would recommend:

```
private static Queue<string> filesToCheck = new Queue<string>();
private System.Timers.Timer copyTimer;

public void Search()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\MCFILE\trrtrt\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            // Display file path.
            if (SHA1Hash.GetSHA1Hash(file) == "1233456") // fake SHA1Hash
            {
                if (!TryToCopy(file))  // See function below
                {
                    filesToCheck.Enqueue(file);
                }
            }
        }
        // Checked all the files once.
        // If there are any in the queue, start the timer.
        if (filesToCheck.Count > 0)
        {
            copyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(CopyTimerProc, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // do your error handling
    }
}

private void CopyTimerProc(object state)
{
    string filename = filesToCheck.Dequeue();
    if (TryToCopy(filename))
    {
        // success. If the queue is empty, kill the timer.
        if (filesToCheck.Count == 0)
        {
            copyTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // File still locked.
        // Put it back on the queue and reset the timer.
        filesToCheck.Enqueue(filename);
        copyTimer.Change(1000, 0);
    }
}

private bool TryToCopy(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        COPYWithReplace(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\MCFILE\Fake2\Test.exe", filename);
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        // log error
        return false;
    }
}
```

The timer is a one-shot that is reset after each time it ticks. The reason I did it this way is to prevent another tick coming along while the previous tick is still processing. After all, it takes time to copy a file.

There's no reason to do this with a bunch of threads. The file system can only do one thing at a time, anyway, and it's not like an extra second or two while you wait for a file to become available is going to hurt anything.

Comment: How many files it can handle? Or it can only handle one file at a time?

Comment: @BigLoser: Any number of files can go into the queue, and the code will check one file per second. It only copies one file at a time, but since they're all on the same disk drive the total amount of time to copy all the files will be about the same--possibly less--because the disk drive can't do more than one thing at a time. The code is pretty simple. Give it a few minutes' study and you'll understand how it works.

Comment: Should I start it from backgroundWorker1 And then turn to run this? Search()

Comment: @BigLoser: That's up to you. You certainly can run this from the background worker. It will perform the first step (building the queue), and the background worker will exit. If there are items in the queue, the timer will continue to tick once per second until the queue is empty.